# Visual Studio "Object Filename" project setting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-settings

We have a few modules with identical filenames in our project.  So I set the `Object Filename` project setting to:

`$(IntDir)\%(Directory)\`.

This works fine except that it uses too much of the file's path.  The path structure is thus:

```
C:\a\b\c\project.sln
C:\a\d\extern
```

`extern` has some stuff like boost in it.  The resulting output is...

```
C:\a\b\c\Release\a\b\c\etc\.obj
C:\a\b\c\Release\a\d\extern\etc\.obj
```

I'd prefer to lop the first two levels off the folder names, so it comes out as..

```
C:\a\b\c\Release\c\etc\.obj
C:\a\b\c\Release\extern\etc\.obj
```

Is there some kind of undocumented path syntax which is similar to `..` but acts against the front of the next folder(s) rather than the back of the previous folders?  Something like:

`$(IntDir)\>>\>>\%(Directory)\` where `>>` moves us up the left hand side of `%(Directory)`?

Thanks in advance for any advice offered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try

```
$(IntDir)\%(RelativeDir)\
```